# Python3 encoding issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, utf

I am studying crawling with python3.
I want to extract only text from html code.

ex) in html

```
<div class='titleArea'>
    "~~~~~ text~~~~"
</div>
```

So, I wrote this code to extract text

```
    title_temp = soup.findAll('div',class_='titleArea')
    print(title_temp)
```

** I know that print(title_temp[0].text) but It does not matter

The result is

[image]

this picture's content is

```
[<div class='titleArea'>
        @#$!$^!@#!@^#!$^!@#!@#!@# 
</div>]
[<div class='titleArea'>
        @#$!$^!@#!@^#!$^!@#!@#!@# 
</div>]
```

***The reason why there is two List is repeated.

I don't want to that text.

What should I do?

I think it's utf-8 problem.

right?

So,

I wrote that

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

but, There was no effect.

Comment: post the url and you request code

Comment: What is mean by "I don't want to that text." ? and please post what exact output you want?

Comment: url is http://hri.co.kr/board/reportView.asp?firstDepth=1&secondDepth=1&numIdx=26865

and I want to exact the only '~~~~~ text~~~~' which is each post's title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('http://hri.co.kr/board/reportView.asp?firstDepth=1&secondDepth=1&numIdx=26865')
r.encoding='euc-kr'
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('div',class_='titleArea')
```

out:

```
[<div class="titleArea">
                                트럼프노믹스가 중국 경제에 미치는 영향
                             </div>]
```

The `chartset` is in html head tag:
[image]

EDIT:
More elegant way:

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('http://hri.co.kr/board/reportView.asp?firstDepth=1&secondDepth=1&numIdx=26865')
r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
```

This will automatically set encoding.

Comment: OH!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Very very very very Thx!!!!!!!!!!
It was a great help.

I have a note that records something important. I will write this on the note.

Very very very very very  Thank you

Comment: @Good answer buddy!

Comment: @Good~~~ Absolutely~~ Thanks

Comment: @ I checked!  Thank you